# Unyson for wordpress - add extension title to builder list

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add a custom title for each extension? For example - textarea in page builder view? For example, if i have title of extension `'Textarea'` and I want to change it to `'Textarea $variable'` and `$variable` should get `title` from `input` in this extension, is it possible to do this easily?
Maybe its possible with a loop counter?

[image]
Here is the image - I want to make the first (orginal) example look like the second.

Here is the link to unyson plugin: http://unyson.io/

I know how to make loop but where should i do it for this extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your shortcode config.php  inside page_builder array add

```
   'title_template' => '{{-title}}{{ if (o.shortcode_title) { }} : <strong>{{= o.shortcode_title}}</strong>{{ } }}',
```

in your shortcode options.php add

```
        'shortcode_title' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => __('Shortcode title', 'fw'),
            'value' => '',
        ),
```